# Defining +/- letter grades as constants. C

Tags: c, arrays, constants, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to complete a lab in which I have to calculate the total Grade Point Average (GPA) from course information given in a linked list of structures. I'm trying to define each letter grade with its appropriate grade point ('A' = 4.0, "A-" = 3.7 ...). The course grades are stored in arrays of chars. I'm able to use the `#define` derivative to define the letter grades A,B,C,D,E, but I am having trouble defining the +/- grades. Is using the `#define` derivative the proper way to achieve this task? and if so, would someone be able to show me the proper syntax.

```
/* Definition of a data node holding course information */
  struct course {
    int term;
    char name[15];
    char abbrev[20];
    float hours;
    char grade [4];
    char type[12];
    struct course *next;
  };



float gpa ( struct course *ptr )
{
  float totalhours;
  float gpa;
  float gradepoints;

  while (ptr != NULL )
    {
      totalhours += (ptr->hours);
      gradepoints = (ptr->hours * ptr->grade);
    }
  gpa = (gradepoints / totalhours);
}
```

Comment: gpa = (gradepoints/totalhours);

Comment: I'm going to suggest right away that you advance that ptr to the next one in your list or it will be a cold day before that while-loop ever exits.

Comment: Why not call them A_PLUS and A_MINUS? If that won't do, the reason lies in facts or code that you haven't provided.

Comment: ahh yes, thanks!
-WhozCraig

I'm receiving the letter grades as input. The possible inputed values are {A = 4.0, A- = 3.7, B+ = 3.3, B = 3.0, B- = 2.7, C+ = 2.3, C = 2.0, C- = 1.7, D+ = 1.3, D = 1.0, E = 0.0}
Other grades, UEN, EN, R, I, etc, are ignored.

Comment: 'before that while-loop ever exits' ... but when it does, ptr will be NULL, resulting in UB. Presumably that last line should be ` gpa = (gradepoints / totalhours);` ... which still yields UB if there are no courses. A hint for people who aspire to be programmers: learn to attend to details , and read your code after you write it.

Comment: I would name them A_PLUS and A_MINUS, but the letter grades are input from a set of accepted inputs: {A- = 3.7, B+ = 3.3, B = 3.0, B- = 2.7, C+ = 2.3, C = 2.0, C- = 1.7, D+ = 1.3, D = 1.0, E = 0.0} Other grades, UEN, EN, R, I, etc, are ignored.} I suppose I can handle each letter grade individually, but I believe that would be pretty inefficient. I haven't been able to troubleshoot my gpa function b/c I have yet to solve this problem. It was included for clarity. @JimBalter

Comment: 'I would ... but ...' -- Yes, I figured something like that but the info you provided was very incomplete. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a map, or a dictionary, which is not natively supported in C. You can implement a simple map for your use case as an array of `struct`s as such:

```
struct GradeInfo {
  char *grade;
  float value;
};
struct GradeInfo GRADES[] = { {"A", 4.0}, {"A-", 3.7}, ..., {NULL, 0.0}};
```

Then loop over this array inside your for loop (fixing a few more bugs):

```
float gpa ( struct course *ptr )
{
  float totalhours = 0.0;
  float gradepoints = 0.0;

  for (; ptr; ptr = ptr->next)
    {
      float grade = -1.0;
      struct GradeInfo *info;
      for (info = GRADES; info->grade; ++info) {
        if (!strcmp(ptr->grade, info->grade)) {
          grade = info->value;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (grade < 0) {
        continue;
      }
      totalhours += (ptr->hours);
      gradepoints = (ptr->hours * ptr->grade);
    }
  if (!totalhours) {
    return 0.0;
  }
  return (gradepoints / totalhours);
}
```

Comment: Your array *is* a map. Maps can be implemented as linear arrays, binary trees, or hash tables (as well as other data structures that are variants of those).

Comment: This code still has a bug ... a wily student can invoke UB by taking no courses.

Comment: I know it is a map. I am saying C doesn't have a native map type such as in python or perl or even C++ STL. That is, you don't get the syntactic sugar of using `[]` or the likes.

Comment: I have no way to know what you know, just what you wrote. What you "are saying" was not said in your answer. And you're conflating syntax with "native" ... many systems provide these data structures in libraries without building them into the syntax (this is certainly true of C++).

Comment: And I reiterate: When you write "what you are looking for is a map", you are misleading readers because that array *is* a map. And when you talk about "native map type" ... a native map type can be implemented as a linear array. Some sophisticated systems (e.g., Scala) actually do so for small maps.

Comment: Your edit still isn't perfect, but it's better. Thanks for taking my comments into consideration.

Comment: @epsalon In your Grade Structure is there anyway to default all other values as 0?

Comment: It's actually easier, just change `float grade = -1.0` to `float grade = 0.0` and remove the `if (grade < 0) {` clause.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is string literals, not variables with those names ... you could define macros, but it just adds a pointless extra level since the mapping is fixed. e.g.,

```
// grade_string is a string read from the input
float grade_value;

if (strcmp(grade_string, "A") == 0)
    grade_value = 4.0;
else if (strcmp(grade_string, "A-") == 0)
    grade_value = 3.7;
etc.
```

There are a couple of more compact ways you can do this.

1) Create an array of mappings, e.g.,

```
struct {
    char*  string;
    double value; 
} grades = { {"A", 4.0}, {"A-", 3.7}, etc. };
```

and loop over this array, comparing the strings to grade_string and extracting the value. e.g.,

```
int ngrades = sizeof grades / sizeof *grades;
int i;
for(i = 0; i < ngrades; i++)
    if (strcmp(grades[i].string, grade_string) == 0)
    {
        grade_value = grade[i].value;
        break;
    }

if (i == ngrades)
    /* invalid grade */
```

2) Use a hash table. This would be advisable if you had a large number of mappings.